# How to add a collectionView with custom view inside a tableview cell in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

i need to add a collection view inside a view in tableview cell.
the below image describes the exactly what i what need.

```
tableView
- tableViewCell
 - contentView
     -monthView
     -detailedView
         -collectionView
           - collection Cell
               -detailedImageView
```

i have added collectionview inside the detailedView(tableview cells second view). But i don't know whether i need to create collectionView cell.swift file or not and how to do the entire process??

Comment: you can consider collectionview inside table cell as normal collectionView! and it depends on you if you need to create custom collectionviewcell or not! i will prefer to create collectionview cell.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati can you please give a link or description related to that. As i am new to iOS.

Comment: This link can help you : https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Comment: @Pipiks Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create collectionView cell file. Here is some example code for you, first create array of contentOffset for collectionViews.

```
var contentOffsets = [Int : CGFloat]()
```

then you can set tag-s to each row collectionViews to recognize which collectionView delegate method is called

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: booksListCellId) as! BooksListCell
        cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let tableCell = cell as! BooksListCell
        tableCell.collectionView.dataSource = self
        tableCell.collectionView.delegate = self
        tableCell.collectionView.reloadData()
        if let offset = contentOffsets[tableCell.collectionView.tag] {
            tableCell.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: offset, y: 0), animated: false)
        }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let tableCell = cell as! BooksListCell
        contentOffsets[tableCell.collectionView.tag] = tableCell.collectionView.contentOffset.x
}
```

And implement your collectionView dataSource and delegate methods in ViewController which contains tableView

Here is [tutorial](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/) which might help you.